# How to call a JavaScript function using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript

There is a website which consists of main frame and some additional ones (they're responsible for parsing inserted data). When I start to edit a record, new frame appears. In the source code I see some JavaScript scripts added. Some of them come from site directories, but also there are some defined in the `<head>` section of the frame. And there is a function defined, let's call it `parseData(input){...}`, which is then called upon pressing "Save" link.

Is there any way to assign a keyboard shortcut to execute saving? There are no ids defined for the "Save" link, only `href` and `class`.

I tried bookmarklets*, but was stuck on joining the frame URL and the JS function call. Any other ideas?

Edit: * bookmarklets are meant to be launched using Shortcut Manager-like web browser extension.

Edit2: I'm not developing the website. I have read-only access to it.

Comment: did you try googling: https://www.google.com/#q=javascript+key+event

Comment: `document.frameName.functionName()`

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad: As I wrote above in edits, I do not develop this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use pure javascript to bind, say, "enter" to the function parseData, you could use:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    keycode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(keycode == 13){      // '13' is the keycode for "enter"
        e.preventDefault();
        parseData(input);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use jQuery with this plugin to create keyboard shortcuts.
Have a look at this:

> https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

You may do something like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', null, 'ctrl+s', saveFunction);
```

Comment: Would this work in a bookmarklet? I'm asking, because I can't edit the site code.

Comment: Your function might look like this: function saveFunction(input){ parseData(input){...} }